# Writing new line to file in perl

Tags: perl

I'm learning perl and writing a script to output all contents in the directory tree of the script to a file. The problem is in the text file the entire output is on one line even though I'm including "\n". I have the save code printing to the console and I get the desired results there, which is one entry per line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Cwd;
use File::Find;
use strict;

my $file = "temp.txt";
my $dir  = getcwd;

unless ( open FILE, '>>' . $file ) {
    die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
}

find( \&print_type, $dir );

sub print_type {
    if (-f) {
        print FILE "File: " . "$_\n";
        print "File: " . "$_\n";
    }
    if (-d) {
        print FILE "Directory: " . $_ . "\n";
        print "Directory: " . $_ . "\n";
    }
}
close FILE;
```

I also tried putting a \n before the "Directory : " and that didn't work either.

Comment: Works for me, what OS are you on?

Comment: Did you forget that you are appending to `temp.txt` and not overwriting it? So that it might look like the output never changes?

Comment: I'm on windows 7, using cygwin to run my scripts and coding with notepad++. Ok, so the file has the new lines when I open in emacs, just not in notepad on windows. It also shows up in notepad++ and wordpad. So simple... I've been trying to figure this out for close to an hour. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Before you get form any bad habits I would start using the lexical 3-arg `open`. You can read about it [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Eg. `open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")`

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question. (Windows notepad doesn't recognize Unix-style `'\n'` line terminators.) You can post an answer yourself and accept. BTW, a more idiomatic way to write your `open` call is: `open my $FILE, '>>', $file or die "$file: $!\n";`

Comment: @KeithThompson I've no problem using notepad to read perl output files in Windows. Must be a cygwin specific problem in that case.

Comment: @TLP - Absolutely a Cygwin thing.  Perl for Windows uses Windows text conventions, while Cygwin aims to be Linux-compatible.

Comment: Note that Windows Wordpad *does* recognize Unix-style line endings.

Comment: @TylerHills: As Keith said, you should post your own answer and accept it.  Once you have your code working as desired, you may also want to post it over at codereview.stackexchange.com so Perl experts can comment on how to improve it. It's a good way to learn idioms and community best practices that aren't always evident in books and tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the code works just fine, but I using Windows notepad to read my output file and it doesn't recognize "\n", I just needed to open it up in just about any other text editor to see that (notepad++, wordpad, emacs).

It may be that notepad could have worked if I weren't using Cygwin.

Comment: If you want the output in a format that notepad recognizes, `open FILE, '<<:crlf', 'input.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

open the file in APPEND mode or WRITE mode,and use the opened file descriptor for writting and appending data to the file, using PRINT stantment in perl. 
IN Linux only the "\n" are considered,not for WINDOW users,so Linux users 
append a extra character at every line end called NEWLINE "\n";